# Find a date in a column and paste data array in neighbouring cells

Tags: excel, vba, date, find

Hy guys, I have the following issue:
I have 2 files- A and B
In file A I have a precise date in cell A1
In range c3:z3 i have values that I want to copy and paste in file B

File B has a list of dates in column A.

The issue: the procedure has to match the date from file A, cell A1 with one of the dates in file B and then paste the values from File A, cells c3:z3 in the neighboring cells

So far I came up with this, but I get an error about the "With" and don't know how to fix it

```
Sub copy_GeoFac()
 'get date
   Windows("File_A.xlsm").Activate

    Dim data As Date
     data = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "A").Value
     Range("C3:Z3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.copy

    Windows("File_B.xlsx").Activate
     Dim FindString As Date
     Dim Rng As Range
     FindString = CLng(data)
     With Sheets("GEOF").Range("A:A")
     Worksheets("GEOF").Activate
      Set Rng = Range("A:A").Find(data)

    Rng.Offset(0, 1).Select
  Selection.Paste.Value
  End With

    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you even using the With block for? In the 4 lines inside the With block, I don't see you ever take advantage of the With block.

Comment: Well, I'm newbie and learning from forums and instructions, so I'm trying to adapt code I find from different sources. The WITH came from such a piece of code.

Comment: Okay well here's how With blocks work... The point of With Sheets("GEOF").Range("A:A") is so that you can use .Find(data) instead of Sheets("GEOF").Range("A:A").Find(data). Use With blocks when you are going to be performing multiple operations on the the variable you activate the With block on.

Comment: If it were me, I would get rid of the With block here because you are only referencing Sheets("GEOF").Range("A:A") once inside of the With block.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the value in A1 of the first worksheet is in column A of the target spreadsheet?? If your found range comes back null, this code should throw a With Block Variable Not Set error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me with one change. Replace:

```
Selection.Paste.Value
```

With:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

There is no Value method of Selection.Paste. That is not valid syntax. This replacement will get your code working for a copy and paste values. Obviously you still need to modify your code to accomodate when the date can't be found in the output spreadsheet but that's a simple if statement.

Comment: Perfect! That worked nicely. I just removed the "With"

Answer (score 0):

So the final code looks like this:

'sell ENEMONA
    Windows("Daily_Trading volumes_template.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("Schedules").Activate
        If Range("AA13").Value > 0 Then
    Range("C13:Z13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.copy

```
Windows("EG_Sell.xlsx").Activate
Worksheets("ENEM").Activate

 Set Rng = Range("A:A").Find(data)
 Rng.Offset(0, 1).Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
'copy prices
Windows("Daily_Trading volumes_template.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("Schedules").Activate
    Range("AH13:BE13").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.copy
   Windows("EG_Sell.xlsx").Activate
Worksheets("ENEM").Activate

 Set Rng = Range("AC:AC").Find(data)
 Rng.Offset(0, 1).Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
```

I added an If to check whether the range I am interested in has any values to be copied. The second copy procedure gets some data that is relevant to the first range and pastes it in the appropriate sheet.